# Unable to postMessage from angular js application to Angular 10 application using iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, iframe, cross-domain

I have two applications , one is angular js application and other is angular 10 application which are running in my local.I need to access a page from Angular 10 using iframe and need to post some message to the  Angular 10 application using iframe from angular js application.

But i am unable to verify using below code weather postMessage is successful or not and also is there any issue connecting to new Angular application while sending the message. There are no errors in the console of the application.

**Angular JS application code:**
This is running in local on port 8090. Added this below code in one file called index.js file.

```
var iframeUrl = "http://localhost:4200/indexing";
var htmlContent =  "<iframe id='myframe' src="+iframeUrl+" "+"frameBorder='0'"+ "></iframe>";
newElement = angular.element(htmlContent);
$compile(newElement)($scope);
element.replaceWith(newElement);
var ifrmaeWindow= newElement.get(0).contentWindow; // Getting iframe window object
ifrmaeWindow.postMessage('Hello World!','http://localhost:4200/');
```

**New Angular 10 application :**
This application is running in local on port 4200. below is the listener code added in index.html

```
<script> 
      window.addEventListener("message",function(message){
       console.log("Received msg in angular="+message.origin);
       console.log("Received msg in angular="+message.data);
      },false);
</script>
```

Please let me know what is wrong in this code flow and why it is not sending messgages using postMessage. Also how do i verify whether the problem is in received end or sender end.
Any help on this would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two applications running on different ports are actually considered different domains and iframes will be blocked via same origin policies:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

In order to get around this in your applications you should first try specifying `document.domain = "localhost"` in both applications and then they should be able to communicate whilst on different ports

Also, within your angular application you may find it easier to add a `HostListener` binding for the events, i.e.

```
@HostListener("window:message", ["$event"]) onPostMessage(event: any) {
    if (event.origin === "http://localhost:8090") {
      console.log("message from iframe", event);
    }
```

Comment: Added  document.domain = "localhost" in both the applications but still not receiving iframe message . In Angular 10 application , added this code document.domain = "localhost" in index.html and in appComponent.html.  Also added event listener code using @HostListener in appComponent.ts .

Answer (score 0):

Adding to chrismclarke ans, added a timeout as well while calling postMessage function solved this issue.

Here is the block of code in Angular js application.

```
try{
                         var ifrmaeWindow= newElement.get(0).contentWindow;
                         setTimeout(function(){ ifrmaeWindow.postMessage(jwToken,'http://localhost:4200/indexing'); }, 5000);
                         console.log("message posted");
                     }catch (e) {
                         console.log("Exception=="+e.message);
                     }
```

@chrismclarke thanks a lot for your response :)